# How can I get an Apple Magic Mouse2 to scroll?

Tags: release-juno, mouse

I'm using Juno and Kernel 4.18 and I would like to get my Magic Mouse2 scrolling working. So far everything I have tried has failed to get the Magic Mouse2 to use the `hid_magicmouse` kernel driver. It will only use the `hid_generic` driver.

Has anyone got this working? If so I would love to hear back so others can get their Magic Mice fully functional.

Sincerely,
Ralph.

Comment: Welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. I have made some changes on your post to make it look better though your choice of words DO describe your problem well.